# 'function' object has no attribute 'order_by'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

i am creating a simple blog website in django and have a model which contains time at which the blog will be published when in views i am trying to sort the post according to time it is giving error 'function' object has no attribute 'order_by'

my views.py:

```
class AboutView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'blog/about.html'


class Postlistview(ListView):
    model = Post

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now.order_by('-published_date'))
```

my models.py :

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def approve_comments(self):
        return self.comments.filter(approved_comments=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    create_date = models.DurationField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_comments = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comments = True
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_list')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it is rather like this:

```
return Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')
```

the order_by must be outside of your filter.

Comment: Also missing the parenthesis, should be `timezone.now()`